# Can programs be embedded into WordPress?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress

Before I begin, I have only just started learning how to code so please presume no prior knowledge. Everything I learn from you guys will be a first for me :)

My friend has a website created using WordPress and has asked me if I can figure out how to implement a program into his page. Specifically, he wants the site to contain a playable computer game that interacts with his page.. like desktop destroyer for example.

What I need to learn:

1) I need to know what language wordpress uses to build their pages

2) Do i need to learn another language like ruby on rails and embed that into the page?

3) Where to start...

I'm pretty much starting this completely from scratch so any other helpful guidance is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress uses PHP to build it's pages.  I think it would be very hard to make a video game in PHP:  AFAIK there hasn't been much in the way of graphical library work done for it.

What you would probably end up doing is to make a standalone game, probably using Javascript and Html5 (Flash used to be the best choice for this but of course it's not supported in iOS which makes it a bad choice now). Get your game working in an empty browser page, then you can embed it into your wordpress site.

If you've already **got** the game, and just need to include it in the wordpress page then that's simple.  You can just embed it: it runs client-side so php doesn't even have anything to do with it (PHP just runs on the server, like Ruby on Rails).

EDIT: just realised, it's not just "very hard" to write a game in PHP, it's impossible, since it's a server-side tech and the game engine would need to run in the browser.  Duh. You could of course handle the back end with php - saving and loading data from a database for example.

Answer (score 0):

> Where to start

Look at what you want to achieve - you want to make a "game" in a Wordpress site - this will be less about [Wordpress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress) and more about the game.

`@Max Williams` summed it up pretty well - a "game" online is comprised of two elements - the front-end and back-end.

--

**Games**

The back-end is basically an API which connects to the DB & server. This would be where the likes of `PHP` / `Rails` would come in - a way for you to interact with data on your server

Even games such as [`World Of Tanks`](http://worldoftanks.com/) use this setup; the `front-end` gives you an interface to interact with the data provided by the `back-end`.

In reference to your PHP / framework question, you need to realize that your `Wordpress` site will just serve a framework of pages, in which you'll be able to include a game. The inclusion of the game would be to load either a `flash` or, even better, a `java` app which will be dynamic & [`sprite-based`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprite_%28computer_graphics%29)

The `front-end` app will basically take your inputs / interactions, and send them to the backend. This will typically by done with a perpetual `websocket` connection, but can be achieved in other ways too

Finally, for each `request` which is received by the server, it will `respond` with data the app has to factor into the game experience. Sounds complicated, but it's quite simple (not easy) when you think about it logically

Comment: "The front-end app will basically take your inputs / interactions, and send them to the backend."  This suggests that you have an MVC system running where the model and controller functionality is done at the back end, ie the server.  I don't think this is sustainable for a game that's expected to run in real time (ie that has frames-per-second and constant interaction).  For a real-time game you would need to have the game controller/models loaded in the front end too, and just use the back end for some persistence functionality, eg saving and loading data at the start and end of a game.